# Show the Gaussian Integers form a ring, by showing that it's a subring of a certain field

Tags: ring-theory

I know that there are certain features of a ring, e.g. commutativity, two binary operations, an identity etc. but how would i go about proving this for the Gaussian integers? and how would i do it, by proving it's a subring of a field?

Comment: What is your definition of the Gaussian integers?? I'm used to defining them as a subset of the complex numbers, but in that case there's nothing to your question, except proving that the Gaussian integers are closed under the ring operations.

Comment: =i can't edit it for the life of me, but it is Z[i] = {a+bi | a,b in Z}..and then yeah, i guess showing that they're closed is really what i need to do. Just how do i go about that?

Comment: Basically the question is trying to get you to see that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is the ring of integers of the number field $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. It is quite a silly question though since you can quite easily show it is a ring without knowing this connection.

Comment: It's the "quite easily shown" bit i'm stuck on. I have no idea where to start :/ sorry if i sound stupid

Comment: Show that if you take two elements of $\Bbb Z[i]$, then their sum, product, and negatives are in $\Bbb Z[i]$ too.